# Github Action: Creating namespace using kubectl in order to deploy the build

Tags: kubernetes, workflow, github-actions, continuous-deployment, amazon-eks

I am creating a GitHub workflow action, to deploy the build into an integration cluster and for that first, I wanted to create a namespace using kubectl, but I am getting an error:  `error: You must be logged in to the server (Unauthorized)`

Here is my action.yaml snippet

```
        uses: cancue/eks-action@v0.0.2
        env:
          aws_access_key_id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          aws_secret_access_key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
          aws_region: $AWS_REGION
          cluster_name: $EKS_CLUSTER_NAME
          kubeconfig: ${{ secrets.INTEGRATION_CLUSTER_SECRETS }}
        with:
          args: |
             kubectl create ns namespace:pr#${{ github.sha }}
```

I am new to writing action workflows.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of data does `kubeconfig` contain? If you are using EKS default authentication, it must execute `aws eks get-token`, and the user fetching the token must be included in auth configmap. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/add-user-role.html

Comment: Hey @jordanm , It's just the credentials and the endpoint for the service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try out the

```
- name: verify deployment
      uses: kodermax/kubectl-aws-eks@master
      env:
        KUBE_CONFIG_DATA: ${{ secrets.KUBE_CONFIG_DATA }}
      with:
        args: create ns <namespace-name>
```

however your config looks good but **makesure** you have added the proper data for **kubeconfig**.

Also, check `access_key` and `secret_key` you are using have the access to **EKS** cluster.

Example : https://github.com/marketplace/actions/kubectl-aws-eks

**Quick fix** :

Once your access & secret set in environment use the command to featch the config from AWS, and you can remove adding the config file in Gitaction seceret.

```
aws eks update-kubeconfig --region ap-south-1 --name <Cluster name>
```

**Secrets**

**KUBE_CONFIG_DATA** – required: A base64-encoded **kubeconfig** file with credentials for Kubernetes to access the cluster. You can get it by running the following command:

```
cat $HOME/.kube/config | base64
```

Comment: hey @harsh, thank you for the solution, the actual issue was with access credentials. The solution you provided, also working for me. :)

Comment: hey @NitikaKuhar, New to writing action still resolve it quickly. Glad to hear that issue is resolved :)

Comment: thank you @harsh, actually, I'm working on this issue for the last 2 days, and the solution you suggested, i tried that also, but at that time it is also giving me the same error. I forgot to check the access to the EKS cluster, after you mentioned I checked that and it works.

Comment: Aww...! Impressive reader you are thn noticed that line and took it seriously, i just wrote that note after reading `Unauthorized`, to check EKS access `coincidentally` that was the only issue. Even before suggesting to check EKS access, i thought it's a very small thing, if a person performing action he/she knows more about it however all miss the minor configs :)